# How can I show only parts of geom_smooth prediction?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph which involved both a `geom_point()` function and a `geom_smooth()` function.

I would like to crop the `geom_smooth()` function at a certain x-value, BUT only after all its values have been used to calculate the smoothed curve (i.e. I do NOT want to use `xlim()`, which will remove the values from being used for plotting).

Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
test <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:10,100,rep=TRUE)))
g <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = test, aes(x = X1, y = X2))

t_i <- test
t_i$group <- as.factor(as.numeric(cut(t_i$X1, 25)))
summar_t <- t_i %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(y_mean=mean(X2),
             y_sd=sd(X2),
             c_mean =mean(X1,na.rm=T),
             n =n()
             )
summar_t$t_2sd <- summar_t$y_mean + summar_t$y_sd*2

g2 <- g + geom_smooth(data = summar_t, aes(x=c_mean, y = t_2sd), se=FALSE, method = lm, formula=y~poly(x,2), color = "black", linetype=3)
```

[image: Current image]
[image: Desired image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the argument `xseq` – which is passed to `StatSmooth$compute_group` – as follows :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, xseq = 100:200, col = "red")
```

Result

[image]

Comment: This did the trick. Hint for anyone else looking, remember it'll do it at integer intervals by default... used: xseq = seq(0,2, length=100)